# Pass cmd line arguments from pm2 to argparse

Tags: python, command-line-arguments, argparse, pm2

I'm using pm2 to start python script using pm2 process file, like so:

`pm2 start ecosystem.json`

I'm also using `argparse` to capture cmd line arguments for the python script. How should I pass the cmd line arguments from pm2 to my python file, i.e. if I want pm2 to run the python script like so:

`python script.py --port 55555`

I have tried:

`pm2 start ecosystem.json -- --port 55555`

and adding `"args" : "--port 55555"` to `ecosystem.json`. But both didn't work : (.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try `pm2 start script.py -- --port 55555` ?

Comment: Yup that works. Also, `pm2 start ecosystem.json -- --port=55555` (= sign addition) also works. And adding args to JSON file as above also works. I used port 66666 that wasn't available (that's why JSON args method failed)

Comment: Indeed. Port numbers are limited to 1-65535 range.